# Specify sudo password for Ansible

Tags: ansible

How do I specify a sudo password for Ansible in non-interactive way?

I'm running Ansible playbook like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini \
    --user=username --ask-sudo-pass
```

But I want to run it like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini \
    --user=username` **--sudo-pass=12345**
```

Is there a way? I want to automate my project deployment as much as possible.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/560106/how-can-i-implement-ansible-with-per-host-passwords-securely

Comment: In the intervening years, the `--ask-sudo-pass` has changed to the more generic `--ask-become-pass` command line option.

Comment: Ended up here when looking for a solution to put sudo passwords in an extra file and encrypt it. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73112035/2074869). Just added `ansible_become_password`.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You can pass variable on the command line via `--extra-vars "name=value"`. Sudo password variable is `ansible_sudo_pass`. So your command would look like:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --user=username \
                              --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=yourPassword"
```

**Update 2017**: Ansible 2.2.1.0 now uses var `ansible_become_pass`. Either seems to work.

**Update 2021**: ansible_become_pass is still working, but for now, we should use -e instead of --extra-vars

Comment: From the security perspective the best answer, if you add the following: `history -c` after execution of the yml.

Comment: @kiltek: *or* add an extra space at the beginning of the line (in bash) which will _*not*_ write the line to `.bash_history`.

Comment: Not a good practice to pass in passwords on command line. Anybody will be able to see the password in the process list, while command is executing...

Comment: @PavelChernikov Good point. Yes, anyone can see the full process list by default. But that can and should be changed by mounting `/proc` with `hidepid=2` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244357/194848

Comment: still, just don't do it. --ask-sudo-pass

Comment: As many have said above, never put your password in commands, especially sudo ones. I'm surprised this variable is supported in the first place. Use of it should be punished cruelly by ansible.

Comment: @scrutari It is perfectly valid in some situations: Eg: Change from a default, world-known, initial password, to inject user's public ssh key... Think initial configuration of a freshly re-imaged system.

Comment: If you want to run Ansible on a GitLab CI/CD runner and the password lives in a protected repository variable and is passed to the runner at merge time, there's no way to interactively provide a password. If the entire pipeline and environment around the passing of the password on the command line is secured, then this posture is fine.

Comment: How you passing the password in  command line !

Answer (score 301):

[The docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) **strongly** recommend against setting the sudo password in plaintext:

> As a reminder passwords should never be stored in plain text. For information on encrypting your passwords and other secrets with Ansible Vault, see [Encrypting content with Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#vault).

Instead you should be using `--ask-become-pass` on the command line when running `ansible-playbook`.

Previous versions of Ansible have used `--ask-sudo-pass` and `sudo` instead of `become`.

Comment: Yes, I can see why this is recommended. However, when we use Ansible as a part of deployment process, what is the better way to automate this? It's not very convenient to stop in the middle of deployment process and ask user to input the sudo password.

Comment: Note --ask-sudo-pass can be abbrieviated to -K, however, as far as I can see, there's no way of handling a playbook running on multiple servers with different passwords (it only asks you once), so I think passwordless sudo is the way to go.

Comment: Does not seem to work. but next suggestion ("some-host ansible_sudo_pass='foobar'") does

Comment: --ask-sudo-pass was deprecated earlier, in 1.9

Comment: I'd love to update the answer with a source link if you have one.

Comment: @SlavaFominII If you are in need of passwords and want to automate, I recommend using ansible-vault to store sensitive data.

Answer (score 134):

Probably the best way to do this - assuming that you can't use the [NOPASSWD solution provided by *scottod*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870083/specify-sudo-password-for-ansible/22201707#22201707) - is to use Mircea Vutcovici's solution in combination with [Ansible vault <sup>*Archived*</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315074733/https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html#running-a-playbook-with-vault).

For example, you might have a playbook something like this:

```
- hosts: all

  vars_files:
    - secret

  tasks:
    - name: Do something as sudo
      service: name=nginx state=restarted
      sudo: yes
```

Here we are including a file called `secret` which will contain our sudo password.

We will use ansible-vault to create an encrypted version of this file:

```
ansible-vault create secret
```

This will ask you for a password, then open your default editor to edit the file. You can put your `ansible_sudo_pass` in here.

e.g.: `secret`:

```
ansible_sudo_pass: mysudopassword
```

Save and exit, now you have an encrypted `secret` file which Ansible is able to decrypt when you run your playbook. Note: you can edit the file with `ansible-vault edit secret` (and enter the password that you used when creating the file)

The final piece of the puzzle is to provide Ansible with a `--vault-password-file` which it will use to decrypt your `secret` file.

Create a file called `vault.txt` and in that put the password that you used when creating your `secret` file. The password should be a string stored as a single line in the file.

From the Ansible Docs:

> .. ensure permissions on the file are such that no one else can access your key and do not add your key to source control

Finally: you can now run your playbook with something like

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -u someuser -i hosts --sudo --vault-password-file=vault.txt
```

The above is assuming the following directory layout:

```
.
|_ playbook.yml
|_ secret
|_ hosts
|_ vault.txt
```

You can read more about Ansible Vault here: [https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html <sup>*Archived*</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315074733/https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html)

---

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html

Comment: Note: as of ansible 1.9, it appears that you can no longer use the ansible_sudo_pass (or ansible_become_pass) variable: "fatal: [...] => Missing become password"

Comment: I'm using this solution in production, jenkins stores the vault password as an obfuscated environment variable, writes it at runtime in a temporary file and proceeds to call ansible.

Comment: or more simply: ``ansible-vault create group_vars/all/ansible.yml`` and add ``ansible_sudo_pass: yourpassword`` there. No need to change playbooks or inventory

Comment: Tried this but I got this error: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}`

Comment: What good is a vault if you store the password to the vault in plain text right next to it?

Comment: What you could do is store the vault in RAM, e.g. /tmp/vault-passwd.txt - so you just need to recreate it on restart of machine - seems a good balance of risk/convenience.

Comment: Kind of late to answer it. But the good of the vault is that each developer can have their vault.txt file with keys to the vault outside of the repository that gets checked into source control. And thus every secret can be hidden in the repository and checked into github...except the one password that the authorized developers have in some 600 permission file hidden in their home directories. Or maybe the Jenkins CI has it hidden in its credentials.

Comment: @Erik We can use `--ask-vault-pass` instead

Comment: What to do if we have more than 1 server and we have different root user password for them?

Answer (score 50):

Looking at the code ([`runner/__init__.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/runner/__init__.py#L340)), I think you can probably set it in your inventory file :

```
[whatever]
some-host ansible_sudo_pass='foobar'
```

There seem to be some provision in `ansible.cfg` config file too, but not implemented right now ([`constants.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/constants.py#L172)).

Comment: A great way to configure this securely would be to store this in the `host_vars` or `group_vars` directory and then encrypt the file using [ansible-vault](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html)

Answer (score 41):

I don't think ansible will let you specify a password in the flags as you wish to do.
There may be somewhere in the configs this can be set but this would make using ansible less secure overall and would not be recommended.

One thing you can do is to create a user on the target machine and grant them passwordless sudo privileges to either all commands or a restricted list of commands.

If you run `sudo visudo` and enter a line like the below, then the user 'privilegedUser' should not have to enter a password when they run something like `sudo service xxxx start`:

```
%privilegedUser ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/service
```

Comment: @bschlueter so you are endorsing bad practice?

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea. Using --ask-sudo-pass makes sense to me.

Comment: @simone cittadini I totally agree as in fact that is the answer I was going to give. This one is a security risk.

Comment: It is less of a security risk if you are using passwordless sudo to deploy to staging/prod, but want to use these answers to skip having to type your local laptop login password when deploying to your localhost every 15 minutes all day every day.

Comment: How do you add this line using Ansible?

Answer (score 25):

The *sudo password* is stored as a variable called `ansible_sudo_pass`. 
You can set this variable in a few ways:

**Per host, in your inventory hosts file** (`inventory/<inventoryname>/hosts`)

```
[server]
10.0.0.0 ansible_sudo_pass=foobar
```

**Per group, in your inventory groups file** (`inventory/<inventoryname>/groups`)

```
[server:vars]
ansible_sudo_pass=foobar
```

**Per group, in group vars** (`group_vars/<groupname>/ansible.yml`)

```
ansible_sudo_pass: "foobar"
```

**Per group, encrypted** (`ansible-vault create group_vars/<groupname>/ansible.yml`)

```
ansible_sudo_pass: "foobar"
```

Comment: Sholud be like the following: note the doublequotes:
`
[server]
10.0.0.0 ansible_sudo_pass="foobar"
`

Answer (score 19):

You can set the password for a group or for all servers at once:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_sudo_pass=default_sudo_password_for_all_hosts

[group1:vars]
ansible_sudo_pass=default_sudo_password_for_group1
```

Answer (score 15):

I was tearing my hair out over this one, now I found a solution which does what i want:

**1 encrypted file per host containing the sudo password**

/etc/ansible/hosts:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user=myuser ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa

[some_service_group]
node-0
node-1
```

then you create for each host an encrypted var-file like so:

```
ansible-vault create /etc/ansible/host_vars/node-0
```

with content

```
ansible_sudo_pass: "my_sudo_pass_for_host_node-0"
```

how you organize the vault password (enter via --ask-vault-pass) or by cfg is up to you

based on this i suspect you can just encrypt the whole hosts file...

Comment: Encrypting using vault makes the most sense to me, though I struggled to use them with `ansible-playback`. I had to use `-e @vault/filename.ext` to use the vault with my `ansible-playbook` call.

Answer (score 9):

A more savvy way to do this is to store your `sudo` password in a secure vault such as [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) or [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) and then pass it to `ansible-playbook` using the `-e@` but instead of hardcoding the contents in an actual file, you can use the construct `-e@<(...)` to run a command in a sub-shell, and redirect its output (STDOUT) to a anonymous file descriptor, effectively feeding the password to the `-e@<(..)`.

#### Example

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /tmp/hosts pb.yml \
   -e@<(echo "ansible_sudo_pass: $(lpass show folder1/item1 --password)")
```

The above is doing several things, let's break it down.

- `ansible-playbook -i /tmp/hosts pb.yml` - obviously running a playbook via ansible-playbook
- `$(lpass show folder1/item1  --password)"` - runs the LastPass CLI `lpass` and retrieves the password to use
- `echo "ansible_sudo_pass: ...password..."` - takes the string 'ansible_sudo_pass: ' and combines it with the password supplied by `lpass`
- `-e@<(..)` - puts the above together, and connects the subshell of `<(...)` as a file descriptor for `ansible-playbook` to consume.

#### Further improvements

If you'd rather not type that every time you can simply things like so. First create an alias in your `.bashrc` like so:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
alias asp='echo "ansible_sudo_pass: $(lpass show folder1/item1 --password)"'
```

Now you can run your playbook like this:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i /tmp/hosts pb.yml -e@<(asp)
```

#### References

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-e

Comment: Using a subshell is a very smart idea! For those wondering, here’s what it looks like with 1Password’s CLI: `--extra-vars @<(echo ansible_become_pass: $(op get item <item name> | jq --raw-output '.details.sections[0].fields[] | select(.t=="password").v'))`

Comment: I like this because when I checked bach history, the password wasn't exposed in cleartext. Likely also true of this is that if system auditing is enabled, the command is logged as reading a file, e.g. `/dev/fd/63` and so by the password being in a temp file descriptor, it's not disclosed.

Comment: I used the following for 1 password:
echo ansible_become_pass: $(op item get 1pass_item_name | grep "password:" | awk '{print $2}')

Answer (score 5):

If you are comfortable with keeping passwords in plain text files, another option is to use a JSON file with the --extra-vars parameter (be sure to exclude the file from source control):

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "@private_vars.json" playbook.yml
```

[Ansible has supported this option since 1.3](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

Answer (score 5):

Ansible vault has been suggested a couple of times here, but I prefer git-crypt for encrypting sensitive files in my playbooks.  If you're using git to keep your ansible playbooks, it's a snap.  The problem I've found with ansible vault is that I inevitably end up coming across encrypted copies of the file that I want to work with and have to go decrypt it before I can work.  `git-crypt` offers a nicer workflow IMO.

- https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

Using this, you can put your passwords in a var in your playbook, and mark your playbook as an encrypted file in `.gitattributes` like this:

```
 my_playbook.yml filter=git-crypt diff=git-crypt
```

Your playbook will be transparently encrypted on Github. Then you just need to either install your encryption key on the host you use to run ansible, or follow the instruction on the documentation to set it up with `gpg`.

There's a good Q&A on forwarding `gpg` keys like your `ssh-agent` forwards SSH keys here: https://superuser.com/questions/161973/how-can-i-forward-a-gpg-key-via-ssh-agent.

Answer (score 5):

you can write sudo password for your playbook in the hosts file like this:

```
[host-group-name]
host-name:port ansible_sudo_pass='*your-sudo-password*'
```

Answer (score 5):

My hack to automate this was to use an environment variable and access it via `--extra-vars="ansible_become_pass='{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASS') }}'"`.

Export an env var, but avoid bash/shell history (prepend with a space, or other methods). E.g.:

```sh
     export ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASS='<your password>'
```

Lookup the env var while passing the extra `ansible_become_pass` variable into the `ansible-playbook`, E.g.:

```sh
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventories/dev/hosts.yml -u user --extra-vars="ansible_become_pass='{{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_BECOME_PASS') }}'"
```

Good alternate answers:

- @toast38coza: [simply use a vaulted value for `ansible_become_pass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29213873/5472444). This is decent. However, for the paranoid teams that need to share ansible vault passwords, and execute ansible plays with induvidual accounts, they coudld use the shared vault password to reverse each others operating system password (identiy theft). Arguably, you need to trust your own team?
- @slm's [bash subshell output generated to temp file descriptor and using the `@` prefix to read the ansible variable from the file desriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889884/5472444). Avoids bash history at least. Not sure, but hopefully subshell echo doesn't get caught and exposed in audit logging (e.g. auditd).

Comment: this is the best solution I think. It does not reveal password when use bash with `set -x` .

Answer (score 4):

You can use **ansible vault** which will code your password into encrypted vault. After that you can use variable from vault in playbooks.

Some documentation on ansible vault:
http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html

We are using it as vault per environment. To edit vault we have command as:
`ansible-vault edit inventories/production/group_vars/all/vault`

If you want to call vault variable you have to use ansible-playbook with parameters like:
`ansible-playbook -s --vault-password-file=~/.ansible_vault.password`

Yes we are storing vault password in local directory in plain text but it's not more dangerous like store root password for every system. Root password is inside vault file or you can have it like sudoers file for your user/group. 
I'm recommending to use sudoers file on the server. Here is example for group admin:
`%admin    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Answer (score 4):

Using **ansible 2.4.1.0** and the following shall work:

```
[all]
17.26.131.10
17.26.131.11
17.26.131.12
17.26.131.13
17.26.131.14

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=per
ansible_ssh_pass=per
ansible_sudo_pass=per
```

And just run the *playbook* with this inventory as:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory copyTest.yml
```

Answer (score 4):

After five years, I can see this is still a very relevant subject. Somewhat mirroring leucos's answer which I find the best in my case, using ansible tools only (without any centralised authentication, tokens or whatever). This assumes you have the same username and the same public key on all servers. If you don't, of course you'd need to be more specific and add the corresponding variables next to the hosts:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=home/user/.ssh/mykey
[group]
192.168.0.50 ansible_sudo_pass='{{ myserver_sudo }}'

ansible-vault create mypasswd.yml
ansible-vault edit mypasswd.yml
```

Add:

```
myserver_sudo: mysecretpassword
```

Then:

```
ansible-playbook -i inv.ini my_role.yml --ask-vault --extra-vars '@passwd.yml'
```

At least this way you don't have to write more the variables which point to the passwords.

Comment: Thank you for this!
Made sense and is working for me with one slight modification.  In the mypasswd.yml it had to be
``myserver_sudo:  "mysecretpassword"``  
for it to work for me.
Not sure how to escape that if you have double quotes in your password....

Comment: @furicle If I remember correctly, I intentionally didn't add the quotes, because I had weird characters in my password and this was the only way it worked. *But* the password didn't contain simple and double quotes, so much is true. I guess the issue is the yaml standard in this case. But sure, quoting the value is often standard.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sshpass` utility as below,

```
$ sshpass -p "your pass" ansible pattern -m module -a args \
   -i inventory --ask-sudo-pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call your playbook with `--extra-vars "become_pass=Password"`

[become_pass=('ansible_become_password', 'ansible_become_pass')](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/688ffa4cee260dc12edc0b7d21eb2cfb822201b1/lib/ansible/constants.py#L166)

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum, so nobody else goes through the annoyance I recently did:

AFAIK, the best solution is one along the general lines of toast38coza's above.  If it makes sense to tie your password files and your playbook together statically, then follow his template with `vars_files` (or `include_vars`).  If you want to keep them separate, you can supply the vault contents on the command line like so:

```
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass -e@<PATH_TO_VAULT_FILE> <PLAYBOOK_FILE>
```

That's obvious in retrospect, but here are the gotchas:

1. That bloody **@** sign.  If you leave it out, parsing will **fail silently**, and ansible-playbook will proceed as though you'd never specified the file in the first place.
2. You must explicitly import the contents of the vault, either with a command-line --extra-vars/-e or within your YAML code.  The `--ask-vault-pass` flag doesn't do anything by itself (besides prompt you for a value which may or may not be used later).

May you include your "@"s and save an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Above solution by @toast38coza worked for me; just that **sudo: yes** is deprecated in Ansible now.
Use *become* and *become_user* instead.

```
tasks:
 - name: Restart apache service
   service: name=apache2 state=restarted
   become: yes
   become_user: root
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) password manager, you can use the module [passwordstore](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/passwordstore_lookup.html), which makes this very easy.

Let's say you saved your user's sudo password in pass as

> Server1/User

Then you can use the decrypted value like so

```
{{ lookup('community.general.passwordstore', 'Server1/User')}}"
```

I use it in my inventory:

```
---
   servers:
     hosts:
       server1:
         ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('community.general.passwordstore', 'Server1/User')}}"
```

Note that you should be running gpg-agent so that you won't see a pinentry prompt every time a 'become' task is run.

Answer (score 1):

For new updates

just run your playbook with the flag -K and he will ask you for your sudo password

g.e `ansible-playbook yourPlaybookFile.yaml -K`

from the doc

> To specify a password for sudo, run ansible-playbook with --ask-become-pass (-K for short)

Answer (score 1):

**Just hint to other solution.**
You can to setup your ansible user to run sudo without password (it's default on GCP VMs)

```
sudo visudo
```

add line (tom is a user):

```
tom ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

we Can also Use EXPECT BLOCK in ansible to spawn bash and customize it as per your needs

```
- name: Run expect to INSTALL TA
  shell: |
    set timeout 100
    spawn /bin/sh -i

    expect -re "$ "
    send "sudo yum remove -y xyz\n"

    expect "$ "
    send "sudo yum localinstall -y {{ rpm_remotehost_path_for_xyz }}\n"

    expect "~]$ "
    send "\n"

    exit 0
  args:
  executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it during playbook execution. the syntax is -

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory my.yml \
--extra-vars 'ansible_become_pass=YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE'
```

But that is not a good idea for security reasons.  Better to use ansible vault

First update your inventory file as follows:

```
[cluster:vars]
k_ver="linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic"
ansible_user=vivek  # ssh login user
ansible_become=yes  # use sudo 
ansible_become_method=sudo 
ansible_become_pass='{{ my_cluser_sudo_pass }}'
 
[cluster]
www1
www2
www3
db1
db2
cache1
cache2
```

Next create a new encrypted data file named password.yml, run the following command:

```
$ ansible-vault create passwd.yml
```

Set the password for vault. After providing a password, the tool will start whatever editor you have defined with $EDITOR. Append the following
my_cluser_sudo_pass: your_sudo_password_for_remote_servers
Save and close the file in vi/vim. Finally run playbook as follows:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory --ask-vault-pass --extra-vars '@passwd.yml' my.yml
```

How to edit my encrypted file again

```
ansible-vault edit passwd.yml
```

How to change password for my encrypted file

```
ansible-vault rekey passwd.yml
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, and only add in the variable file:

Example:

```
$ vim group_vars/all
```

And add these:

```
Ansible_connection: ssh
Ansible_ssh_user: rafael
Ansible_ssh_pass: password123
Ansible_become_pass: password123
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you mean ansible_become_pass instead of Ansible_become_pass.

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me...
Created file /etc/sudoers.d/90-init-users file with NOPASSWD

```
echo "user ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL" > 90-init-users
```

where "user" is your  userid.