# Ansible Become password

Tags: ansible

I have a small and simple playbook to make a directory on two other servers which I have saved in a inventory file and passing the name 'dev-edge'.

When I try and run this, I get a:

```
a2s3421.fake.cor.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
a1s3433.fake.cor.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

I can `'ssh niall@g4t7459.houston.hpecorp.net'` so the servers can be reached from the ansible server.

I think this is because I am not passing my password, I have tried to use 'become_pass: XXXXX' but still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to add/request a password in a playbook?
Or is there another reason why I would be getting a unreachable error when running the playbook??

Thanks for the help
Frostie.

**'Playbook'**

---

```
- hosts: dev-edge
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"

  tasks:

    - name: create directories
      become: yes
      become_user: niall
      command: mkdir /opt/apps/niall_test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this by passing the following when running the playbook

 `--extra-vars='ansible_become_pass= XXXXXXX`

Answer (score 5):

To avoid specifying the password on the command line, one shall use `--ask-become-pass`, as told in this answer about [become on sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153708/518853).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the playbook with `--ask-pass` option. Please refer `ansible-playbook --help` for more details.

Excerpt from the help:

```
    -k, --ask-pass      ask for connection password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either run with --ask-pass or use password-less ssh.