# Ansible - Passing password to playbook command which uses --ask-become-pass option

Tags: ansible, sudo

My command line is

```
ansible-playbook *playbook-name* --ask-become-pass
```

In this case `ansible` will ask for the password.

I want to use the same command but without having to put the password interactively. 
something like

```
ansible-playbook *playbook-name* --ask-become-pass < password
```

(which don't work of course)

Comment: you should consider using key based ssh, instead of using password

Comment: yes but my playbook needs the ask-become-pass option in order to switch from user to another. Basically i have two user on my remote machine i used ssh key for the first one and password for the second one. (i switch to the second one using using "become" and sudo.
The password i need to pass here is the password of the user of the ansible master machine itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify sudo password for Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870083/specify-sudo-password-for-ansible)

Comment: not exactly the same issue. Here it it's really related to sudo of the ansible user itself and not the sudo of the remote machine

Comment: It is **exactly** the same issue. You might be confused by the old parameter names, but did you bother to read the accepted answer?

Comment: it did'nt work it does not take the password into account

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my issue by removing the --ask-become-pass option and i set the ansible_become_pass variable in my inventory (and encrypted the password by vault). Therefore, during the sudo operation ansible use the password i provided to "become" another user