# run python script locally using ansible passing remote host has input

Tags: python, ansible

want to fetch remote hosts with out ssh to the remote host i want to run python script local. by passing remote host has input to my python script
by {{ inventory_hostname }}".

```
- hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('web')}}"
      become: true
      any_errors_fatal: yes
      serial: 1
      tasks:
        - name: execute install script
          command: python myscript.py -i "{{ inventory_hostname }}" -f script.cql -u username-p password
          delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

i got the error

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a case of ansible not knowing your sudo password.

see [Specify sudo password for Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21870083/2599522) et al.